# how to insert iboutlets into a array (swift3)

Tags: ios, arrays, button, swift3, iboutlet

I am trying to group multiple iboutets into a array. This will make my coding workflow much faster if its possible to group. I have tried to code my idea but it does not work. What I am trying to do revolves around the let c = part.  Code is below.

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
let c = {
@IBOutlet var a: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var b: UIButton!
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func turnOff(_ sender: Any) {
    c.isHidden = true

}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your needs I see three options:

**1. Outlet Collections**

If you use interface builder, look for the Outlet Collection option when dragging out an outlet.

[image: Outlet Collection]

Here is the syntax for manually creating outlet collections:

```
@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
```

Now you can connect multiple buttons to the collection. The downside is that you no longer have simple access to individual buttons via this outlet.

**2. Computed Property**

If you would like to keep individual outlets for easy access I would probably create a computed property returning a collection:

```
@IBOutlet var a: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var b: UIButton!
var buttons: [UIButton] {
    return [a, b]
}
```

**3. View Hierarchy**

Depending on your layout needs you may be able to put all buttons into a common parent view. Now just hide/unhide the parent view.

**Extending Collections for Option 1 and 2**

The reason why you cannot use `isHidden` on the buttons collection is that Arrays don't have an `isHidden` property. You will have to iterate through the array (Tom Harrington pointed this out in the comments). If you have to do that a lot you can extend arrays of buttons by adding a method that forwards to the `isHidden` property of the array's elements. Here is an example for extending the more general type `Sequence` constrained to `UIView` elements (which includes arrays of buttons):

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == UIView {
    func setHidden(_ hidden: Bool) {
        for view in self {
            view.isHidden = hidden
        }
    }
}

buttons.setHidden(true)
```

Comment: I tried your 2nd function with var buttons: [UIButton] {
    return [a, b]
}. The problem is that buttons.isHidden = true does not work.

Comment: That's because it's an array. You need to change `isHidden` on each item in the array, not on the array itself.

Comment: I there any way I can group all of the buttons to make isHidden more efficient or do I have to do each individually.

Comment: You can put all buttons into a view and hide that view.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the buttons inside a `Stack View`.
2. Drag an outlet from that `Stack View`.
3. Finally you will be able to use `isHidden` property on that `Stack View`.